# Why I cant set 10 fps to output video with mpeg1video codec?

Tags: ffmpeg

ffmpeg shows me that it is supported:

ffmpeg -h encoder=mpeg1video
...
Supported framerates: 24000/1001 24/1 25/1 30000/1001 30/1 50/1 60000/1001 60/1 15/1 5/1 10/1 12/1 15/1

But I got error

I do:

ffmpeg -loglevel level+info -i rtsp://10.110.63.70:554/ISAPI/Streaming/Channels/101/ -n -f mpegts -r 10 -s 672x380 -c:v mpeg1video -b:v 600K tcp://127.0.0.1:56883

and got: [error] MPEG-1/2 does not support 10/1 fps

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not noted in the help as shown above, but only the frame rates 24000/1001, 24/1, 25/1, 30000/1001, 30/1, 50/1, 60000/1001, 60/1 are supported using ffmpeg's `normal` strictness mode, presumably because they are the rates explicitly supported in the MPEG-1 specification.

In order to enable any of 15/1, 5/1, 10/1, 12/1, you need to turn on `unofficial` or `experimental` mode using the `-strict unofficial` option. This needs to be in the encode options (so after the last input).

Note that it's possible some MPEG-1 decoders will reject the content created with this frame rate since it appears to be precluded by any defined profile in the original specification. For maximum compatibility, you may be better using a different codec if you can.

From your example above, your command would become:
`ffmpeg -loglevel level+info -i rtsp://10.110.63.70:554/ISAPI/Streaming/Channels/101/ -n -f mpegts -r 10 -s 672x380 -c:v mpeg1video -b:v 600K -strict unofficial tcp://127.0.0.1:56883`

Reference: https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/libavcodec/mpeg12framerate.c#L24

Comment: Thank alot! Your answer helped me to undrstand.